# multiple async call issue in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm fairly new to node.js so kindly forgive my ignorance, what I'm trying to do is loop through an array of servers and allocate a maximum of 60 tasks to each server. However the incoming number of tasks can be anything between 10 to 200.

So what I'm looking to do assign 60 tasks to the first server, then the next 60 tasks to second server and so on.

I have the following function, which seems to go horribly wrong..

```js
function mount_the_tasks(server_info){
    async.forEach(server_info, function(single_server, callback1){
        Tasks.find({task_status : 0}).limit(single_server.can_perform_tasks).exec(function(err, tasks_for_server){
            async.forEach(tasks_for_server, function(single_task, callback2){
                Tasks.findOneAndUpdate({_id : single_task._id}, {task_status : 1, server_id : single_server.instance_id}, function(err, numberAffected){
                    console.log(single_task.task_id+' -> '+single_server.instance_id);
                    callback2();
                });
            }, function(err){
                console.log('Moving to next server!');
                callback1();
            });
        });
    }, function(err){
        console.log('all done!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Please expand upon *"which seems to go horribly wrong"*

Comment: Well i did a simple test case with 70 tasks, the ideal logic would assign 60 to the first server and 10 to the second server, however the result i'm getting is the first 60 are assigned to server 4 while the remaining 10 are untouched.

One more thing I noticed is that each of the server is getting assigned 60 tasks which implies that Tasks.find with status 0 returns the wrong set of results.

Comment: What is `async`? the async lib i know of doesn't have a forEach method.. Instead, it has each.

Comment: I got that reference from one of the sample code somewhere, however it was initially "each" which somehow returns the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are going through all of the servers in parallel.  What this means is for each server, you're assigning the first 60 active tasks to each because by the time the next server is iterated through, the previous set of tasks aren't done yet so their status is still 0. To fix this, you'll have to use `async.eachSeries` instead when iterating over the servers so that the tasks are marked complete before moving on to the next server.

```
function mount_the_tasks(server_info){
    async.eachSeries(server_info, function(single_server, callback1){
        Tasks.find({task_status : 0}).limit(single_server.can_perform_tasks).exec(function(err, tasks_for_server){
            async.each(tasks_for_server, function(single_task, callback2){
                Tasks.findOneAndUpdate({_id : single_task._id}, {task_status : 1, server_id : single_server.instance_id}, function(err, numberAffected){
                    console.log(single_task.task_id+' -> '+single_server.instance_id);
                    callback2();
                });
            }, function(err){
                console.log('Moving to next server!');
                callback1();
            });
        });
    }, function(err){
        console.log('all done!');
    });
}
```

Another option would be to use `.skip()` to cause each iteration to skip the number of tasks handled by the previous server. This should be a little bit faster than the previous option assuming your server isn't already bottlenecked due to the number of requests being sent simultaneously.

```
function mount_the_tasks(server_info){
    var skip = 0;
    async.each(server_info, function(single_server, callback1){
        Tasks.find({task_status : 0}).limit(single_server.can_perform_tasks).skip(skip).exec(function(err, tasks_for_server){
            async.each(tasks_for_server, function(single_task, callback2){
                Tasks.findOneAndUpdate({_id : single_task._id}, {task_status : 1, server_id : single_server.instance_id}, function(err, numberAffected){
                    console.log(single_task.task_id+' -> '+single_server.instance_id);
                    callback2();
                });
            }, function(err){
                console.log('Moving to next server!');
                skip += single_server.can_perform_tasks;
                callback1();
            });
        });
    }, function(err){
        console.log('all done!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Thank you so much!